# Find the greatest common divisor of the polynomials:

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

a) $X^m-1$ and $X^n-1$ $\in$ $Q[X]$

b) $X^m+a^m$ and $X^n+a^n$ $\in$ $Q[X]$

where $a$ $\in$ $Q$, $m,n$ $\in$ $N^*$

I will appreciate any explanations! THanks

Comment: For part a) just do Euclid's algorithm. Notice that the steps will have a striking resemblance to a run of Euclid's algorithm in computing $\gcd(m,n)$. Part b) will split into cases according to the parity of $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Suppose for simplicity that $\,m\le n\;$ . The roots of $\;x^k-1\in\Bbb Q[x]\,$ are the elements $\,w\in\Bbb C\;\;s.t.\;\;w^k=1\;$ . Now,

$$\left(w^m=1\implies w^n=1\right)\iff w=e^{i\theta}\;\;\text{and}\;\; m\theta\,,\,n\theta\in T:=\{2k\pi\;;\;k\in\Bbb Z\}$$

But $\,m\theta\in T\,$ **for sure** (why?) , so...

Comment: +1 This will work very well. Probably even more efficient than my initial impression of running Euclid :-)

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen. I shall still give some thought to your comment in the other question, haven't forgotten.

Comment: Thanks! I would like if you could to complete all the demonstration, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the formula

$$ a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + a^{n-3}b^2 + \cdots ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1})$$

Comment: As an additional hint. If $m=qn+r$ with $0\le r <n$, then this shows that $x^{qn}-1$ is divisible by $x^n-1$, so when dividing by $x^n-1$, the polynomial
$$x^m-1=(x^m-x^r)+(x^r-1)=x^r(x^{qn}-1)+(x^r-1)$$ leaves remainder ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=mq+r$ with $0\leq r<m $ then
$$x^n-1= (x^m)^q x^r-1=\left((x^m)^q-1\right)x^r+(x^r-1)=(x^m-1)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}x^{mk}\right)x^r+(x^r-1)$$
and 
$$\deg(x^r-1)<\deg(x^m-1)$$

hence by doing the Euclidean algorithm in parallel for the integers and the polynomials, we find
$$(x^n-1)\wedge(x^m-1)=x^{n\wedge m}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\rm\ f\mid x^n\!-\!1,x^m\!-\!1 \!\iff\!\ mod\ f\!:\  ord\, x\mid n,m \!\iff\! ord\,  x\mid gcd(n,m) \!\iff\! f\mid x^{\gcd(n,m)}\!-\!1 $